# Sql query for special record

Tags: sql, t-sql

At the first excuse me for my bad english.

I have two tables:

1. master table:

   ```
   | product id   | pr_name          | remain_Qty        |
   +--------------+------------------+-------------------+
   | 1            | x                | 13                |
   | 2            | y                | 18                |
   | 3            | z                | 21                |
   +--------------+------------------+-------------------+
   ```

   2. Detail Table (This table contain detail data of bought product):

   `+--------------+------------------+----------+--------+
   | date         | pr_id            | Qty      |price   |
   +--------------+------------------+----------+--------+
   | 2010-01-01   | 1                | 3        | 1000   |
   | 2010-01-02   | 1                | 5        | 1200   |
   | 2010-01-01   | 2                | 11       | 1100   |
   | 2010-01-03   | 1                | 4        | 1400   |
   | 2010-01-04   | 3                | 3        | 1300   |
   | 2010-01-01   | 2                | 6        | 1600   |
   | 2010-01-03   | 1                | 7        | 1700   |
   | 2010-01-02   | 3                | 3        | 1300   |
   | 2010-01-01   | 3                | 5        | 1500   |
   | 2010-01-04   | 3                | 7        | 1700   |
   | 2010-01-06   | 2                | 8        | 1800   |
   | 2010-01-07   | 2                | 4        | 1400   |
   | 2010-01-03   | 1                | 3        | 1300   |
   | 2010-01-04   | 3                | 6        | 1600   |
   | 2010-01-08   | 1                | 1        | 1100   |
   +--------------+------------------+----------+--------+`

   sum Qty of product 1 = 23
   sum Qty of product 2 = 29
   sum Qty of product 3 = 21

As a result I want list of the Details table, where the list is sorted by pr_id , date and price, but the sum(Qty) per pr_id don't exceed the remain_Qty of the product_id of the Master table.

For example:

```
+--------------+------------------+----------+--------+
| date         | pr_id            | Qty      |price   |
+--------------+------------------+----------+--------+
| 2010-01-01   | 1                | 3        | 1000   |
| 2010-01-02   | 1                | 5        | 1200   |
| 2010-01-03   | 1                | 4        | 1400   |
| 2010-01-03   | 1                | 1        | 1700   |
| 2010-01-01   | 2                | 11       | 1100   |
| 2010-01-01   | 2                | 6        | 1600   |
| 2010-01-01   | 3                | 5        | 1500   |
| 2010-01-02   | 3                | 3        | 1300   |
| 2010-01-04   | 3                | 3        | 1300   |
| 2010-01-04   | 3                | 7        | 1700   |
+--------------+------------------+----------+--------+
```

Comment: Question itself is not clear because of the bad english :)

Comment: Your output makes no sense, can you pls explain how did you come to such result.

Comment: I agree with @theweeknd. You should have 6 results for product 1 yet you have only shown 4.

Comment: Also please include your rdbms

Comment: it could be something like this: select date, pr_id, Qty, Price
from detailTable
order by pr_id, date, price. But possibly you want the actual remain_Qty. That could be done with a join based on pr_id, but it depends on what you want and how you want it calculated...

Comment: I understand what he's saying. OP wants a query to return as many rows as possible as long as their total price is equal to the remain_Qty value. Product id of 1 has a remaining quantity of 13 so he returns values 3,4,5,1 because they total up to 13.

Comment: @Luminous yeah, we all get that, but you can get the same quantity with the values 7,3,3 with the ID=1, it just makes no sense, i dont believe he wants some random sum that equals the quantity, the price would never be the same, what is the point of that result set???

Comment: @Aliasghar-Yousefian: ترجمه گوگل می تواند شگفتی ؛ شما در حال حاضر سعی که یکی؟ با احترام. ( من برای فارسی بد من بهانه ای )     (google translate can do wonders; did you already tried that one?)

Comment: excuse me for my bad english  and my mistake. i wants a query to return as many rows as possible as long as their total price is equal to the remain_Qty value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More of a clarification than a direct SQL answer.  But what it LOOKS like they may be wanting is based on an inventory being depleted to fill orders from the known available quantity, but even that falls short as the may be missing a second qty of 3 on 2010-01-03 for product 1... which if looking at just ID=1 from his sample data would show...

```
| date         | pr_id  | Qty |price  |  Qty Available to fill order
+--------------+--------+-----+-------+
| 2010-01-01   | 1      | 3   | 1000  | 13 - 3 = 10 avail next order
| 2010-01-02   | 1      | 5   | 1200  | 10 - 5 = 5 avail next order
| 2010-01-03   | 1      | 3   | 1300  | 5 - 3 = 2 avail next order
| 2010-01-03   | 1      | 4   | 1400  | only 2 to PARTIALLY fill this order
| 2010-01-03   | 1      | 7   | 1700  | none available
| 2010-01-08   | 1      | 1   | 1100  | none available
```

With the extra sample record removed, would result in...

```
| date         | pr_id  | Qty |price  |  Qty Available to fill order
+--------------+--------+-----+-------+
| 2010-01-01   | 1      | 3   | 1000  | 13 - 3 = 10 avail next order
| 2010-01-02   | 1      | 5   | 1200  | 10 - 5 = 5 avail next order
| 2010-01-03   | 1      | 4   | 1400  | 5 - 4 = 1 avail for next order
| 2010-01-03   | 1      | 7   | 1700  | only 1 of the 7 available
| 2010-01-08   | 1      | 1   | 1100  | no more available...
```

So Aliasghar, does this better represent what you are trying to do??? Fill the available orders based on which order was entered into the system first, fill as many as possible based on inventory and stop there?

Please confirm by adding comment to this answer and maybe we can help resolve... Also, confirm WHICH Database are you using... SQL-Server, Oracle, MySQL, etc...

Comment: hi dear; correct result is                                                                           | date         | pr_id  | Qty |price  |  Qty Available to fill order
+--------------+--------+-----+-------+
| 2010-01-01   | 1      | 3   | 1000  | 13 - 3 = 10 avail next order
| 2010-01-02   | 1      | 5   | 1200  | 10 - 5 = 5 avail next order
| 2010-01-03   | 1      | 4   | 1400  | 5 - 4 = 1 avail for next order
| 2010-01-03   | 1      | 7   | 1700  | only 1 of the 7 available
| 2010-01-08   | 1      | 1   | 1100  | no more

Comment: i use sql server 2008

Comment: How this can be the correct answer? it add more clarification of your need!

Comment: @AliasgharYousefian, Thanks for marking as answer, but incomplete and I'll work on that and get actual query.  I just explained it better.  Others offer MySQL solutions but you are running SQL-Server.  Does your DETAIL table have an auto-increment "ID" column available to work with such as "DetailID".  Let me know.

Answer (score 2):

Here a working query for pr_id=1 , I used MySql:

```
select final.pr_date, final.pr_id,  count(t_qty) as qty, final.price from
  (select * FROM (select q.pr_date, q.pr_id,  1 as t_qty, q.price , @t := @t + t_qty total
FROM(
SELECT d.pr_date, d.pr_id,  1 as t_qty, d.price
FROM detail_table d
    JOIN generator_4k i
ON i.n between 1 and d.qty
  WHERE d.pr_id= 1
Order by d.id, d.pr_date)  q
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT @t := 0) i)  c
WHERE c.total <= (select remain_qty from master_table WHERE product_id = 1)) final
group by  final.pr_date  , final.pr_id , final.price ;
```

Here [SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/997a6/6/0)

You have to adapt your detail_table to add a technical id as primary key and create some views, I renamed the date column as pr_date, You'll find the schema on the sql fiddle.

Here another query Using SQL SERVER

```
select final.pr_date, final.pr_id,  count(t_qty) as qty, final.price from
(SELECT top(select remain_qty from master_table WHERE product_id = 1) d.pr_date, d.pr_id,  1 as t_qty, d.price
FROM detail_table d
    JOIN generator_4k i
ON i.n between 1 and d.qty
  WHERE d.pr_id= 1
Order by d.id, d.pr_date)  final
group by  final.pr_date  , final.pr_id , final.price ;
```

Here [SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/997a6/19/0)

Answer (score 0):

### Daywise product by info

Beneath a suggested statement.

```
select t2.date,t2.pr_id,t1.pr_name,sum(qty) as qty_buy,sum(price) as amount from master_table as t1
inner join detail_table as t2 on t1.product_id=t2.pr_id
group by t2.date,t2.pr_id

order by t1.date,t2.pr_id
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a hard time to understand what you really wanted.

So if I understood well, you want some data that correspond to a product but do not go over your remained item.

So I coudn't bypass yet the first query that goes over, and only take the remaining from it.

So my query for now just stop until it s get to the remained items allowed

[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fa255d/3/0)

To be able to do what you want, you need to first create a view that generate row based on your quantity.

Like something like

```
> +--------------+------------------+----------+--------+
| date         | pr_id            | Qty      |price   |
+--------------+------------------+----------+--------+
| 2010-01-01   | 1                | 3        | 1000   |
```

turn into something like

```
> +--------------+------------------+----------+--------+
| date         | pr_id            | Qty      |price   |
+--------------+------------------+----------+--------+
| 2010-01-01   | 1                | 1        | 1000    
| 2010-01-01   | 1                | 1        | 1000   |
| 2010-01-01   | 1                | 1        | 1000   |
```

Then you count your rows until your remained item allows you to do it.

After you regroup all of the row by price,pr_id  and date.

VOILA